# can you please elaborate what the print function actually did here step by step?

Tags: python

EXTRACT HELLO FROM THE FOLLOWING CODE

Following is the code to extract, but I'm unable to understand..thanks in advance

```
d = {'k1':[1,2,3,{'tricky':['oh','man','inception',{'target':[1,2,3,'hello']}]}]}

print(d['k1'][3]['tricky'][3]['target'][3])
```

Comment: The `print` function wrote the single string it received as an argument to standard output. I suspect your question is really about how that argument was specified.

Comment: It's all just indexing: what is `d['k1']`? Call it `x`; then what is `x[3]`? Etc.

Comment: yes i guess you're right....i want to know what happened inside the print function ..i'm just a beginner and got confused looking at this..didn't understood what actually print function did there to extract HELLO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to execute this code line by line to understand:

```
# d is a dictionary:
d = {'k1':[1,2,3,{'tricky':['oh','man','inception',{'target':[1,2,3,'hello']}]}]} 
print(d)

print("\n")
#print the value where key='k1'
d1=d['k1']
print(d1)

print("\n")
#d1 is a list.
# print the 4th value of list d1, list's index start with 0.
d2=d1[3]

print(d2)
print("\n")
#d2 is a dictionary 
#print the value where key='tricky'
d3=d2['tricky']
print(d3)
print("\n")
#d3 is list
#print the 4th value of list d3.
d4=d3[3]
print(d4)
print("\n")
# d4 is dictionary
#print the value where key='target'
d5=d4['target']
print(d5)
print("\n")
#d5 is list
#print the 4th value of list d5.
d6=d5[3]
print(d6)
```

Answer (score 1):

`d` is a dictionary with many nested elements.  let's unpack that:
First, there's `k1`, a key which is a list.  The first three elements of `k1` are `1,2,3`.  The fourth element is another dict.

When you say `d['k1'][3]`, you are referencing the fourth element of the list (remember it's [0-indexed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering)), which is this dictionary.

The rest of the arguments follow the exact same pattern.  They extract the third value from the key specified.

Answer (score 1):

It's obviously a very artificial data structure, but you've got a series of nested dictionaries and lists, and the print statement is just peeling down the layers of the onion, one by one.

You can see this if you break down the print statement, layer by layer:

```
print(d['k1'])      # Accesses dictionary by key 'k1'
print(d['k1'][3])   # Accesses list - 4th element
print(d['k1'][3]['tricky'])    # dictionary by key 'tricky'
print(d['k1'][3]['tricky'][3]).# list - 4th element
print(d['k1'][3]['tricky'][3]['target'])  # dictionary by key 'target'
print(d['k1'][3]['tricky'][3]['target'][3]) # list - 4th element
```

outputs:

```
{'k1': [1, 2, 3, {'tricky': ['oh', 'man', 'inception', {'target': [1, 2, 3, 'hello']}]}]}
[1, 2, 3, {'tricky': ['oh', 'man', 'inception', {'target': [1, 2, 3, 'hello']}]}]
{'tricky': ['oh', 'man', 'inception', {'target': [1, 2, 3, 'hello']}]}
['oh', 'man', 'inception', {'target': [1, 2, 3, 'hello']}]
{'target': [1, 2, 3, 'hello']}
[1, 2, 3, 'hello']
hello
```

Answer (score 1):

1) the `print` statement first goes to the key `'k1'` in the dictionary named `d`. the value associated with `'k1'` is a list: `[1,2,3,{'tricky':['oh','man','inception',{'target':[1,2,3,'hello']}]}]`.

2) the 2nd reference is `3` which means the 3rd index in the `list` `[1,2,3,{'tricky':['oh','man','inception',{'target':[1,2,3,'hello']}]}]`. the 3rd element is another dictionary that looks looks this: `{'tricky':['oh','man','inception',{'target':[1,2,3,'hello']}]}`.

3) the 3rd reference is `'tricky'`, which is the `key` in this nested dictionary. the value associated with this key is another list: `['oh','man','inception',{'target':[1,2,3,'hello']}]`.

4) the 4th reference is `3` with points to the 3rd index in this nested list (`['oh','man','inception',{'target':[1,2,3,'hello']}]`). the 3rd value is `{'target':[1,2,3,'hello']}`, which is yet another nested dictionary.

5) the 5th reference is `'target'`, which is the key in this dictionary. the value associated with this key is this list: `[1,2,3,'hello']`.

6) the 6th and final reference is `3`, which is the 3rd index in this nested list. the value in the 3rd index is `'hello'`, so `"hello"` will be the result of this `print()`

Answer (score 1):

This is just a bunch of indexing. First, the data is just nested lists and dictionaries, so we can write a tree for the values to break it down.

```
d - dict - 'k1' - list -- 1
                       |_ 2
                       |_ 3
                       |_ dict - 'tricky' - list -- 'oh'
                                                 |_ 'man'
                                                 |_ 'inception'
                                                 |_  dict - 'target' - list -- 1
                                                                            |_ 2
                                                                            |_ 3
                                                                            |_ 'hello'
```

With this, we just follow the tree, giving a key for `dict`s, and an index for `list`s so that we get to hello.
Doing this, we get `d['k1'][3]['tricky'][3]['target'][3]` to get to hello, which is in fact what we get.

Normally you wouldn't really want to make a tree like this, but it can help to see what these are actually doing.